# Setting up HTTPS Ingress for .NET 8 Application in Azure Container Apps

Tags: azure, docker, .net-8.0, azure-container-apps

I run ASP.NET Core in Docker container in Azure Container Apps

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
#Generate an SSL certificate 
FROM nginx:1.19.1-alpine AS certbuilder
ARG PASSWORD=password
RUN apk update && \
    apk add --no-cache openssl

RUN echo $PASSWORD
RUN openssl genrsa -des3 -passout pass:$PASSWORD -out server.pass.key 2048 && \
    openssl rsa -passin pass:$PASSWORD -in server.pass.key -out server.key && \
    rm server.pass.key && \
    openssl req -new -key server.key -out server.csr -subj "/C=/O=/OU=ou/CN=domain.com" && \
    openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in server.csr -signkey server.key -out server.crt && \
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out server.pfx -inkey server.key -in server.crt -password pass:$PASSWORD

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS base
ARG PASSWORD=password
COPY --from=certbuilder server.pfx certificate/
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Service.Api/Service.csproj", "Service.Api/"]
COPY ["./nuget.config", "./"]
RUN dotnet restore "Service.Api/Service.Api.csproj" --configfile nuget.config
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Service.Api"
RUN dotnet build "Service.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Service.Api.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Service.Api.dll"]

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="https://+;"
ENV ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=443
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password=$PASSWORD
ENV ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/certificate/server.pfx
```

In Azure Container Apps i have configured Ingress HTTP on Port 443.

Here is the image:
[image]

And i have received this error: `upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection termination`

How to resolve the issue?

I have tried to use TCP with `targetPort`:443 and `exposedPort`: anyport. And this is how it is working, but i'm not trying to achieve this.

Comment: Can you once change the targetport to 8080 and run it again

Comment: Still the same error. I've configured Health Probes and in there I've got also a connection refused error.....

Comment: i dont think you can configure self signed cert in container app. container app support https by default and free cert. any specific reason you wanna use a self signed cert ?

Comment: I thought i will need self signed certificate for container to container communication via https. Should i try to remove the certificate from the docker file?

Comment: @Thomas - you are right and this is correct! I've removed the self-signed certificate from the Dockerfile and in the Target Port I entered 8080. And it worked like a charm still on HTTPS! Thank you a lot!

Comment: Good to ear it is working for you :-) so effectively the https termination is done at the ingress controller level (envoy proxy) so between envoy and your container it is http.  you can enable env encryption if required as per this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#mtls

Comment: Is there any way to configure httpS traffic between the envoy proxy and my container?

Comment: This will ensure mutual tls between envoy and your container: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-apps/networking?tabs=workload-profiles-env%2Cazure-cli#mtls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Setting up HTTPS Ingress for .NET 8 Application in Azure Container Apps

Thanks to `Thomos` for suggesting the same point.

The error mentioned suggests that the use of a **self-signed certificate** in your `Dockerfile` is causing an issue.

To resolve the issue, remove the `self-signed certificate`, redeploy the image, and ensure to include the target port **8080** in the container application’s configurations.

[image]

**Output:**

[image]